# Taxes and health insurance: Find SLCSP (second lowest cost silver plan) before 1095As are issued

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, self-employment, health-insurance, colorado

To do 2017 end-of-year tax planning, I need to know the second lowest cost silver plan (SLCP) for my Colorado zip code. I've tried searching my health insurer's site, the state marketplace site, and the government site. And I've tried calling those entities. All to no avail.

If this data available or not? If yes, then how in the devil does one find it?

Important: I know that 1095As are issued in January/February. I want this data now (before December 31st) when I still have an opportunity to make decisions that optimize my tax situation.

Note: You need to know the SLCSP dollar amount to complete form 8962.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT! Kaiser has calculators for current AND past years at

http://kff.org/interactive/subsidy-calculator/

I double checked it's accuracy by entering data from the 1095s from past years. The dollar amounts from the calculators matched the data on the 1095s every time.

When using the calculators, several things to note:

1. If you don't select a state, then you'll get a national average.
2. To see the SLCSP dollar amount, for income you must enter a number that clears the Medicaid threshold. In Colorado in 2016, the number is $22,000.
3. For age, enter your age at the time you enrolled.

Comment: In late December I completed a pro forma of my taxes using the above link for the data I needed for the SLCSP amount. Yesterday I completed my actual taxes using the data from the official 1095. My proforma ObamaCare bottomline was within a $100 of the actual bottomline.